# Build only one Module instead of dependent modules in maven

Tags: maven, build, module

I have a project say "MyProject". It's having 3 modules 'A','B' and 'C'. And I want to build only 'A' module.
The below command is working perfectly.
 `mvn -pl A clean install`.
But my problem is "Module-B is using Module-A" in B's pom.xml. Below is the example.
B's pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>ModuleA</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
```

And I don't want to build Module-B even though it's using Module-A.
Please help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem yet. With `mvn -pl A clean install` you build module A (and not B). So why is it important that module A is used by module B?

Comment: Module-B is having Module A as dependency. So when I try to build ModuleA, Module B also getting build. That's the issue.

Comment: Module B should only be build if you add the `-amd` flag to the build.

Comment: Okay let me brief you my exact requirement. I have a scanner which scans all the files. So when I try to build ModuleA, it's scanning the Module A's files and ModuleB's files also(Which I don't want). Means ModuleB is having dependency of Module A.

Comment: What kind of scanner? I still wonder why it is called for module B as well. Without the `-amd` flag, this should not be the case.

Comment: It scans all the SQL files. So when I try to scan Module-A, it scanned all the files in. Also it's scanning Module-B(Here is issue).

Comment: Then this is probably a configuration of the scanner. I don't think you can configure that on the Maven level, but you probably need to configure the scanner.